# Thymeleaf and SpringMVC, how to use pathvariable

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

My Controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
class MockRestController {

    @RequestMapping(method = [RequestMethod.POST], value = ["/mocks/{id}/start"])
    fun startMock(@PathVariable id: String): ResponseEntity<String> {
        ...
    }
```

This works perfectly:

```
<h1 class="title is-2">
    Mock #[[${id}]] control page
</h1>
```

However, my form action doesn't work:

```
<form action="/mocks/${id}/start" method="post">
```

How can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

try like this. here `${id}` contains your variable value.

```
<form th:action="@{/mocks/{id}/start(id=${id})}" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working.

```
<form th:action="@{'/mocks/' + ${id} + '/start'}" method="post">
```